# CSS: How to change colour of active navigation page menu on dropdown click?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```html
    <div class="menuBar">
<li ng-if="" class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ui-sref="#">
                                ADMIN
</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInDown">
  <li><a href="#" ui-sref="userList">Users</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ui-sref="Roles">Roles</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

When I try to select users or roles in ADMIN tab page is navigating but I want admin to be highligted please let me know how to write CSS. I tried by using active and selected class but its not working; I can't post my full code. Let me know any solution for it.

`<li>` has to be highlited when you select `<a>` in `<ul>`.

I'm trying to change the color of the active or current page navigation link which is selected by the user on my website. What am I doing wrong?

(This is my navbar image I am in ADMIN page but it is not highlighted).

Comment: Please add your css code so far tried

Comment: .dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    background: #8CC152;
}   this is the css for ul listed in li thats it i have lot of css for dropdown-menu and dropdown-toggle but no css for dropdown its a complicated navbar i have lot of classes, could you please give me an idea which class i need to use

Comment: Have you tried :visited class? or :focus class? Focus on your a elements might work.

Comment: @Hunter: it was correct to unformat some text in this question, but watch out for HTML tags that need inline formatting - have repaired it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  Can you please try it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Recaptcha by VividCortex</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("ul li a").click(function () {
                $(".dropdown-toggle").css("color", "#2a6496");
                var ul = $(this).parent().parent().prev();
                ul.css("color", "red");
                var ap = "dh";
            });
        })
    </script>
    <div class="menuBar">
        <span ng-if="" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ui-sref="#">
                ADMIN
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInDown">
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="userList">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="Roles">Roles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ui-sref="#">
                CRUD
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInDown">
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="Insert">Insert</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="Update">Update</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ui-sref="#">
                MASTERS
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInDown">
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="RegionList">RegionList</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" ui-sref="CountryList">CountryList</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```